# UTF-8 polish letters

Tags: polish

I have a problem with my engineering thesis, because I have to save my latex project in UTF-8 in pdf. Everything is ok, till I copy some text from pdf into another text editor (for example notepad). Then I have some strange signs in the place of polish letters. I have to change that, because it is needed to check my thesis by anti-plagiarism system.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newgeometry{tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm}
\geometry{bindingoffset=2cm}

\usepackage{makecell,interfaces-makecell}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=15pt]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother


\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}   
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty} 

\begin{document}
ąęćżź...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: When I copy text from compiled pdf to notepad, signs like ą, ę, ć ... are replaced by artifacts, example: https://ibb.co/yhwVFfc

Comment: No show your latex code. It matters.

Comment: ok, I added latex code

Comment: I get ąęćżź when copying from the PDF file. What TeX distribution are you using? Please, show the first ten line or so from the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load `cmap` package:

```
\usepackage{cmap}
```

As writing in documentation, it is package "to make the PDF files generated by
pdflatex "searchable and copyable" in acrobat reader and other
compliant PDF viewers".

Comment: It's working! Thank You!